# How do I get the progress bar to work in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, progress-bar

I made a timer in Swift using the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  //  @IBOutlet var ProgressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    
    var hours: Int = 0
    var mins: Int = 0
    var secs: Int = 0
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //ProgressBar.progress = 0.0
    }

    @IBAction func didTapAddButton() {
       // var progress: Float = 0.0
        //ProgressBar.progress = progress
    
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier:"date_picker") as! DateViewController
        vc.title = "New Event"
        vc.completionHandler = { [weak self] name, date in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.didCreateEvent(name: name, targetDate: date)
            }
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    private func didCreateEvent(name: String, targetDate: Date){
        self.title = name
        let difference = floor(targetDate.timeIntervalSince(Date()))
        if difference > 0.0 {
            let computedHours: Int = Int(difference) / 3600
            let remainder: Int = Int(difference) - (computedHours * 3600)
            let minutes: Int = remainder / 60
            let seconds: Int = Int(difference) - (computedHours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)
           
            print("\(computedHours) \(minutes) \(seconds)")
            hours = computedHours
            mins = minutes
            secs = seconds
            
            updateLabel()
            
            startTimer()
        }
        else{
            print("negative interval")
        }
    }

    private func startTimer() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            if self.secs > 0 {
                self.secs = self.secs - 1
            }
            else if self.mins > 0 && self.secs == 0 {
                self.mins = self.mins - 1
                self.secs = 59
            }
            else if self.hours > 0 && self.mins == 0 && self.secs == 0 {
                self.hours = self.hours - 1
                self.mins = 59
                self.secs = 59
            }
            
            self.updateLabel()
        })
    }

    private func updateLabel() {
        label.text = "\(hours):\(mins):\(secs)"
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a progress bar somewhat show how much time is left. I want the bar to be full when there is no time left. How should I do this?

I tried searching how to do this but Google wasn't helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing you want to do is bring all your values for `hour`, `minutes`, and `seconds` into a singular combined value, represented as something like `totalSeconds` or whatever you want.

```
var hours: Int = XXX
var minutes: Int = XXX
var seconds: Int = XXX
var totalSeconds: Int = 0
totalSeconds = getTotalSecondsFrom(hours, minutes, seconds)

func getTotalSecondsFrom(hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) -> Int {
    let hoursToSec = (hours * 60) * 60
    let minutesToSec = minutes * 60
    return hoursToSec + minutesToSec + seconds
}
```

Once you have all of your values brought down into a singular value now you have a representation for calculating a progress bar's maximum limit. Remember that a progress bar can only have values betweeen `0.0` and `1.0` which is perfect for a `percentage` calculation. In the interest of explaining in a way that will make sense for learning, let's look at this from a different perspective. How can we get a `percentage` from a total maximum, then map it to a value in the range of `0.0 -> 1.0`?

```
func getCompletedPercent(currentSeconds: Int, totalSeconds: Int) -> Float {
    return Float(currentSeconds) / Float(totalSeconds)
}
```

Why does this work? Well, let's assume our total seconds are `5000` and current is `500`. Doing the math, `500 / 5000 = 0.1` which is `1/10th` or `10%` of `5000`, which is exactly what we're looking for. With this knowledge in hand all you need to do at this point is set your progress bars maximum to `1.0` and then every second, in your timer, update it's current progress using the functional examples `getTotalSecondsFrom(...)` and `getCompletedPercent(...)`. Of course your version may vary slightly, but the concepts are the same.